# Simplest method for the following ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that if $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$, the solution is $c=y/x.$

What is the simplest thinking method for the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$d\left(\frac{y}{x} \right) = \frac{x(dy) - y(dx)}{x^2} = 0 \implies \frac{y}{x} = c = cst$$

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables gives $\frac{1}{y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dx$ then integrate both sides and use $e^{\ln(y)}=Ce^{\ln(x)}$ to get $y=Cx$.